# Is the action of the option -D in Maven temporary or not?

Tags: maven

I need some clarifications here.
If I am doing

```
mvn -Dnewproperty=value
```

Will it permanently add the property to the pom.xml of my project?
If so,is there a way to delete a property from the pom.xml?

Comment: It sets a system variable for the current running VM. So it lasts as long as the VM is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's temporary. You will need to specify it every time you run Maven.